# Post value to webapi controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

Here is my WebAPi controller and html form. The request is correctly routed to the method in the controller by myValue is always null. I thouht this was a valid way to post getting it from some tutorials.

Controller:

```
[Route("add")]
public string Post([FromBody]string  myValue)
{
    return string.Format("HAIAA: [{0}]" , myValue);
}
```

View:

```
<form id="formOne" method="post" action="ninja/add">
    <input type="text" name="myValue" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Inspect how the form is submitting the data. because for `[FromBody]` to work the submit value will have to be in the format `"The entered value"`. Remove the `[FromBody]` attribute and it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot POST a simple type parameter using an HTML form to a Web API action. Either use a complex type containing your parameter:

```
public class MyFormData {
    public string myValue { get; set; }
}
```

Changing your controller signature:

```
[Route("add")]
public string Post([FromBody]MyFormData data)
{
    return string.Format("HAIAA: [{0}]" , data.myValue);
}
```

Or use AJAX for POSTing the single value to your action:

```
$('#formOne').submit(function () {
    $.post('ninja/add', { "": $('input[name=myValue]').val() })
        .success(function () {
            //do something
        })
        .error(function () {
            //show error
        });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming that! Now i can leave that behind me and move on. Jeeez been spending so much time on this. Plenty of articles says you can though, but apparently you cant.

Answer (score 1):

There are caveats to using post parameters.

Here is the best resource I have found:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Most likely:

```
// POST api/values
public string Post([FromBody]string value) {
  return value;
}
```

and this weirdness:

the value you need to send over needs to be

```
{ '': value }
```

this is the jquery

```
$.post('ninja/add', { '': value });
```

Not exactly sure how to fix it in your example........but I think I am giving you the correct value to try to send.

Comment: Im not posting from jQuery. Im doing a normal HTTP form post.

Comment: Yeah....I realize that.  I'm just giving you the jquery equivalent.  You need to format what you send over to the post, that is the point I'm making.  :)

Comment: But I would probably switch to jQuery myself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once, and it worked for me to use `System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormDataCollection`, which takes an object representing the data sent as `application-x-www-form-urlencoded`

Try

```
public string Post(System.Net.Http>formatting.FormDataCollection data)
{
    return string.Format("HAIAA: [{0}]" , data.Get("myValue"));
}
```

Comment: This works! I know it already. Im trying to figure out what the rules for gettin form data is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
[Route("add")]
        public string Post(System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormDataCollection myValue)
        {
            NameValueCollection nvc = form.ReadAsNameValueCollection();
            string value = nvc.Get("myValue");
            return string.Format("HAIAA: [{0}]", value);
        }
```

Comment: This is too complicated. It works with parameter (FomrDataCollection data)
And in the body just data["myValue"]. You dont need the nvc object.

Comment: @Lautaro Thanks for the suggestion, I tried these solution before , but somehow I wasn't able to get data. That's why I tried the above solution which worked for me